# Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "panelApi" has not been added to the store

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

There are couple of these questions on here already but essentially as the title says I'm getting the above titled warning when I run my tests.

```
//panel.service.ts
export const panelApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'panelApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: baseURL, // currently just a localhost:5555
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    fetchComponentData: builder.query<any, string>({
      query: endpoint => endpoint,
      transformResponse: (response: any) => response.data,
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useFetchComponentDataQuery
} = panelApi;

// store/index.ts
export const store = configureStore({
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  reducer: {
    [panelApi.reducerPath]: panelApi.reducer
  },
  middleware: gdm =>
    gdm()
      .concat(panelApi.middleware)
});
```

Everything is where it should be, can someone point me in the correct direction at all?

Comment: Are you really using this `store` instance in your tests? Are you maybe resetting it in some way between tests?

Comment: @phry it's possible that the store instance is being reset but I'm not entirely sure where we would be doing that. 

The stacktrace for the error is suggesting that the api is not available in a component that isn't even using the query but it's children are. 

Could that be it?